# How to make my code accepts an input

Tags: java

I would just like to ask on how can I make my code to just get the input instead of declaring it? Here's my program. I want to input different atomic numbers and not just "37" like what's in my code. Don't mind my comments, it's in my native language. Thanks!

```
 public class ElectConfi {    

      public static void main(String s[]) {

            int atomicNumber = 37;
            String electronConfiguration = getElectronConfiguration(atomicNumber);
            System.out.println(electronConfiguration);
      }
      public static String getElectronConfiguration(int atomicNumber) {

            int[] config = new int[20]; //dito nag store ng number of elec. in each of the 20      
             orbitals.
            String[] orbitals = {"1s^", "2s^", "2p^", "3s^", "3p^", "4s^", "3d^", "4p^", "5s^", 
            "4d^", "5p^", "6s^", "4f^", "5d^", "6p^", "7s^", "5f^", "6d^", "7p^", "8s^"};  
            //Names of the orbitals
            String result="";
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++) //dito ung i represents the orbital and tapos ung j 
            represents ng electrons
            {
                    for(int j=0;(getMax(i)>j)&&(atomicNumber>0);j++,atomicNumber--) //if atomic 
                    number > 0 and ung orbital ay kaya pa magsupport ng more electrons, add 
                    electron to orbital ie increment configuration by 1
                    {
                            config[i]+=1;
                    }
                    if(config[i]!=0)        //d2 nagche-check to prevent it printing empty 
                    orbitals
                    result+=orbitals[i]+config[i]+" ";      //orbital name and configuration 
                    correspond to each other
            }
            return result;
       }
       public static int getMax(int x) //returns the number of max. supported electrons by each 
       orbital. for eg. x=0 ie 1s supports 2 electrons
       {
            if(x==0||x==1||x==3||x==5||x==8||x==11||x==15||x==19)
                    return 2;
            else if(x==2||x==4||x==7||x==10||x==14||x==18)
                    return 6;
            else if(x==6||x==9||x==13||x==17)
                    return 10;
            else
                    return 14;
      }
 }
```

Comment: by using Scanner to test?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` and get the user input

Using `Scanner`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input atomic number");
int atomicNumber = scanner.nextInt();
```

Using `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int atomicNumber = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getElectronConfiguration(int atomicNumber) {}
```

This method accepting any `int` value and will return `String` result. so you only need to provide different number as input. There is no change required in this method.

How to provide different inputs?

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to do that.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input atomic number");
int atomicNumber = scanner.nextInt();
```

Now call your method

```
String electronConfiguration = getElectronConfiguration(atomicNumber);
```

What are the other ways?

You can define set of values for `atomicNumber` in your code and you can run those in a loop

Comment: Did this but get errors. Here's my latest codes. pastebin.com/g55d7Pp1

Comment: @user3604330 check this. http://ideone.com/J7GhC9, same code. It is not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user input from a command line argument:

```
public static void main(String s[]) {

        if (s.length == 0) {
           // Print usage instructions
        } else {
            int atomicNumber = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
            // rest of program
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get input from command line arguments by doing below :

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String inputLine = scanner.nextLine(); //get entire line
 //or
 int inputInt= scanner.nextInt();//get an integer
```

Check java.util.Scaner api for more info - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Hope this helps!